# vba multiple checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and i'm struggling to figure out code to copy and paste certain values to a different worksheet

I've got some code that does work, however it is very slow to run:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B2")

If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:B3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:B3")

If CheckBox3.Value = True Then Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:B4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A4:B4")
...............

If CheckBox53.Value = True Then Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A54:B54").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A54:B54")
```

I've got each checkbox linked to the cell next to it, e.g E2, E3, E4 etc to display True/False depending on whether is been clicked or not. Also

I'm thinking that a for loop would be better,e.g for "a=2 to 53" and use the true/false values in column E,  however i'm unsure how to modify the range of cells within a for loop so that it increases just like "a", so A2:B2, A3:B3 etc

Also, the other problem with this code is that is copies the values to the same cells within the 2nd sheet. What would be the best way to get it to paste the values to the next available row.

If anyone could point out somewhere there's some similar example code that would be extremely useful so that i can learn how to do it myself.

Kind regards

Chris

---

edit with working code

This is the code that i've come up with to fulfill the criteria outlined above

```
Sub checkbox()

For i = 2 To 53

Sheets("Sheet1").Select    'activates sheet 1

If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "E").Value = True Then    ' checks for true value
    Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Select    'selects range of cells for copying
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select    'selects sheet 2
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select    'selects next available empty row
    ActiveSheet.Paste    'pastes value               
    Else
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: These are ActiveX checkboxes?

Comment: You are asking for three things, to _create a VBA loop_, then wanting to paste cells into the _next available row_ and also asking for example code. If you search for each of these it will help you find example code and you can give it a go, if you get stuck come back and ask for some help. Dont use copy, you can amend to make it run slighly faster by: `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:B2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B2").Value`

Comment: after looking through here for guidance on it, i've managed to come up with some code that works :)

Comment: @ChrisA you could answer your own question by pasting the code you used as an answer, this may help someone who comes across your question in the future.

Comment: @5202456 , I did edit my original post with the working code